# How can I write this function (image) in Latex?

Tags: latex

How can I write this function (image) in Latex?

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question, and really belongs on [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Sorry. Thanks for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should lay a sufficient foundation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example
\begin{document}

$f \colon \{0,1\}^N \rightarrow \{0,1\}^M$

$f \colon \{0,1\}^N \mapsto \{0,1\}^M$

\end{document}
```

You can change the spacing around `:` (or `\colon`) as needed, perhaps using `f~\colon~`.

Comment: Why isn't that stuff migrated to TeX.SX?

Comment: @Johannes_B: I vote-to-close every time, suggesting migration, but it is really slow.

Comment: I thought here would be the real robo-reviewers.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I made a suggestion about a possible trusted-user privilege: [What privilege should 30k users get?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/252705/168244)